# Position fixed, but scroll on <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this situation:

- my website, which I am creating, has a left sidebar, which must be set to height 100%, while scrolling the webpage, and the content inside it is definitely over 1000px height.
- because of the height of the content, I get vertical scroll on this sidebar element, and when my content has enough content, I get another scroll for this  section.

What I have to do is to, somehow, transfer, scroll from the "fixed" element to the main page scroll...

I hope that you can understand me...

I hope that this screenshot, can also help you to understand what I ask:

[link](http://content.screencast.com/users/apopovic/folders/Snagit/media/5bafc7e9-03b4-41c0-a191-92fd36547a07/02.22.2015-23.54.png)

Thank you in advance for you answers.

Comment: Now add a little code or a reduced test case so people can understand and try and help you

Comment: @Djave I have added the screenshot....

Comment: Its a strange layout choice (having the scrollbar on the opposite side of the page than the thing you are scrolling) but essentially you want to 'position:fixed' the _right_ side of your page, and remove fixed from the left hand side. Then, the body scroll bar will end up controlling the left side while the right section stays still. You'll run into problems fast though if you make it responsive...

Comment: @Djave Yes, it must be bootstrap 3 responsive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question got me interested, so I gave it a try.

You could have your sidebar set up like so:

```
#sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    min-height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    /* ... */
}
```

Now, to make it scroll, we can play with its `margin-top` css property:

- If we scroll down, we decrement it unless we scrolled past its
  height.
- If we scroll up, we increment it unless it's above zero.

I created a `ScrollingSidebar` class with 2 functions in order to deal with that:

```
// ScrollingSidebar class
// Define some variables and bind events
function ScrollingSidebar(el){
    this.sidebar = el;
    var that = this;
    that.updateVariables();
    document.addEventListener('scroll',function(){that.scrollSidebar();});
    window.addEventListener('resize',function(){that.updateVariables();});
}

// Updates variables used for calculation
ScrollingSidebar.prototype.updateVariables = function(){
    this.height = parseInt( getComputedStyle(this.sidebar).height );
    document.body.style.minHeight = this.height + 'px';
    this.winHeight = parseInt( window.innerHeight );
    this.previousScrollPos = Math.floor( document.body.scrollTop ||
                                   document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
                                   document.body.parentNode.scrollTop
                                 );
    this.scrollSidebar();
};

// Updates the sidebar's margin-top
ScrollingSidebar.prototype.scrollSidebar = function(){
    var curScrollPos = Math.floor( document.body.scrollTop ||
                                   document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
                                   document.body.parentNode.scrollTop
                                 );
    if(this.previousScrollPos < curScrollPos){
        this.sidebar.style.marginTop =  - Math.min(-parseInt( getComputedStyle(this.sidebar).marginTop ) + (curScrollPos - this.previousScrollPos),
                                                  this.height-this.winHeight) + 'px';
    } else {
        this.sidebar.style.marginTop = Math.min(0,parseInt( getComputedStyle(this.sidebar).marginTop ) + this.previousScrollPos-curScrollPos) + 'px';
    }
    this.previousScrollPos = curScrollPos;
};
```

You can use it like so:

```
// Create an instance of ScrollingSidebar
var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
var x = new ScrollingSidebar(sidebar);
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo (with a small amount of content)

#### JS Fiddle Demo (with a lot of content)

Note: *I did not take the time to comment my code very well, but if you have any question about it or any problem with it, feel free to ask.*

*If your website is responsive and you don't want this method to be used on small screens, you might want to consider using a condition to disable it.*

Comment: I have implemented this in my design, but, I am faced with some bugs. When I have less content in "left" column, I get "two" scrollbars.
Here is jsfiddle, so you can take a look [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xzv2tLxd/).
Thank you so much for your help.